# biztalk custom pipelinecomponent split messages in send

Tags: biztalk, custom-pipeline-component

Is it possible to create a custom pipelinecomponent that splits a message in 2 messages, but in the send port?
I have seen that it is possible in the receive port using the disassembler interface, but can we use this in a send pipeline component?
Can someone give me an example to how to accomplish this?

Thx

Comment: No, it is not. A single message - aka stream of bytes - only ever goes out of a BizTalk send port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically send ports are made for assembly and not dis-assembly, hence why the interface for a send port component has an assemble aspect to it.  Is sounds like this would be a good opportunity to split the message via filters and use multiple send ports to send out the 2 messages.  I've seen a few folks do this with writing the msgs to the file system, etc. but that screams bad practice.  Think of splitting the messages before the pipeline components are needed.

Comment: Ok, I understand that the message can only be split in the disassemble stage :( I solved my problem by inserting an orchestration that splits the message when I want to.. Thx